# Link being replaced not expected way when using preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I've a `array` with regular expressions I use to replace URL's/hashtags with links using `preg_replace`:

```
$regs = array('!(\s|^)((https?://|www\.)+[a-z0-9_./?=;&#-]+)!i', '/#(\w+)/');
$subs = array(' <a href="$2" target="_blank">$2</a>', '<a href="/hashtag/$1" title="#$1">#$1</a>');

$output = preg_replace($regs, $subs, $content);
```

If `$content` have a link, for ex: `https://www.google.com/`, it replaces correctly; if have a hashtag followed a text, for ex: `#hello` replace too, however, if have a link with a hashtag, for ex: `https://www.google.com/#top` the replacement is as follows:

```
#top" target="_blank">https://www.google.com/#top
^^^^                                         ^^^^
```

and only the highlighted parts turn into links.

How to fix?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: My expected output is like: `https://www.google.com/#top` but it only detect the #top (thus breaking the html) and no detect the completely link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your second regex in array is also matching part after `#` in string.

Change your regex to:

```
$regs = array('!(\s|^)((https?://|www\.)+[a-z0-9_./?=;&#-]+)!i', '/(?<=[\'"\s]|^)#(\w+)/');
$subs = array(' <a href="$2" target="_blank">$2</a>', '<a href="/hashtag/$1" title="#$1">#$1</a>');
$content = 'https://www.google.com/#top foobar #name';

# now use in preg_replace
echo preg_replace($regs, $subs, $content);
```

It will give you:

`<a href="https://www.google.com/#top" target="_blank">https://www.google.com/#top</a> foobar <a href="/hashtag/name" title="#name">#name</a>`

Comment: It is working now, but It is no longer detecting only hashtags like: `#test`